# Redis-RQ not executing jobs

Tags: django, redis

I have a question but it turns out I have similar problems to other Github threads that haven't been resolved yet, might as well ask it here.

I am running Django and is using redis-rq to execute background jobs. Unfortunately, it doesn't execute jobs from the default queue. I have already tried to rename it but no progress so far.

Have you guys had this similar event before, and how did you resolve it? Thanks!